# Delphi 11 - tcp:64311: cannot resolve name: No address associated with hostname Exiting

Tags: android, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

Trying to launch an Android Application previously made on 10.4.2 in the new delphi 11 but this error occurs.
Some forums discuss about adb.exe if it can find the device, it can, the device is plugged in and is recognizable by the IDE.

Adding clarification: The app being tested is a default "helloworld" app: blank screen with a label in the center saying "hello world".

The pictures below show the configuration for SDK 30 but I already tried with the SDK 29 and SDK 28, no luck. Also tried NDK 17.2b from 10.3.3 Rio, NDK 20.1 from 10.4.2 and this time NDK 21.2 from Alexandria, but none of them works.

- With the lower NDKs (17.2 and 20.1) the app installs, open but freezes on the splash screen and then android hangs it with TCP 64311 error.
- With latest NDK v21 from Google, the app freezes on the splash screen, gives a method error with Android JNI class and hangs the debugger, then android hangs the app.
- With v21.2 or v21.3 the app launches properly but throws a TCP 64311 error and hangs the debugger.
- With NDK 22 it doesn't even configure properly.
- With a mix of NDK 22 for all options except the ones from NDK_BASE/platforms/android-23 and NDK v21 for those, the app launches, but throws TCP 64311 error along with another signal 39 error.

Any ideas on what should I do?

SDK configuration:

[image: SDK configuration]

NDK configuration:

[image: NDK configuration]

JAVA OpenJDK configuration:

[image: JAVA OpenJDK configuration]

Comment: One possible reason is that your phone can't connect to the internet. Be sure to check your wifi/5G and make sure <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> is added to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I am trying to debug via USB cable, the internet shouldn't interfere in this case, but regardless it is properly connected to the internet and the error still occurs.

Comment: Another option is that you're still using the old GCM for push notifications (i had the same error here), youll need to switch to the firebase implementation: https://blogs.embarcadero.com/firebase-android-push-notification-support-with-rad-studio-10-3-1/

Comment: This should help better, just in case : https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Firebase_Android_Support

Comment: I'm not using anything, its a "helloworld" app: blank screen with just a label saying "hello world".

Comment: zero entitlements enabled as well?

Comment: Only the default ones, that comes with any new blank application. Its the OOB test

Comment: the push notifs entitlement was giving me issues here, you could try disabling that for a sec if it's active. Beyond that im kind of stumped as well i fear.

Comment: Any luck on this one - Mobius? I'm trying to port my app to Android 11 and am getting the same error. It was working fine on Android 10 but now I can't even install to an Android 10 device from the IDE. So it doesn't appear to be an issue with Android 11. I tried a simple datetimepicker app that ships with Delphi and get the same error regardless of what android version I use. Did you install FIrebase as per @TS suggestion?

Comment: @LeonardM. I'm not using any external depedencies but the app just doesn't run on my android device, waiting on IDERA to see if they provide a solution for this issue.

Comment: My old development machine installs the app just fine using SDK 25 on 10.4.2 but my new one fails using the same configuration. I translated this post from a german web site https://forum-delphi-cz.translate.goog/index.php/topic,17396.0.html?_x_tr_sl=cs&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=nui,sc and then noticed I had made a copy of my gdbserver on the old machine. When I used an older version of gdbserver, the error went away. Now, the application launches on the phone but the IDE hangs and locks the connection to the phone. So I am still working on that problem. Maybe this will help you out.

Comment: @LeonardM. Please read the steps that I did on the original post, I tried the default delphi configuration for 10.3.3 (SDK 28, NDK 17.2), tried the default configuration for 10.4.2 (SDK 29, NDK 20.1) and tried the preeinstalled configuration on 11.0 (SDK 30, NDK 21.3). The defaults don't work neither changing around some NDKs. It feels that it is a NDK issue but couldn't point out what yet

Comment: It looks like the gdbserver I am using is from NDK 17.2 installation of 10.3. I copied the gdbserver from the default directory of: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-17b_20.0.36039.7899\prebuilt\android-arm\gdbserver. The date on the file is 06/07/18 and the size is 583KB. I copied the file to my new development machine and then pointed the gdbserver location to where I installed the file. I would think that if you were using the 10.3.3 NDK configuration it is probably already pointing to this gdbserver but it may be worth verifying.

Comment: Just an update. I downloaded Delphi 11 onto a new development machine. I got the same error when trying to deploy under SDK 30 but was able to successfully deploy using SDK 29. However, I had use a run parameter of -debugport=5000. Still looking for a solution for SDK 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this solution, which actually works ;-) at a Delphi Czech Forum. Embarcadero installs a patched NDK with Delphi, so if you install one by your own, you need to use a patched "gdbserver" file (For instance with RAD Studio 11 "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-21-22.0.42600.6491\android-ndk-r21\prebuilt\android-arm\gdbserver"), here you my find two files, the original gdbserver file renamed to gdbserver.orig and a patched one named gdbserver. You need to copy this file where whenever you installed and pointed at Delphi the NDK inside the "prebuilt\android-arm\gdbserver" folder

Comment: Indeed that worked with original NDK 21.3 just pointing the gdbserver to embarcadero's one for the HELLO WORLD example, but for a project previously built in 10.4.2 to be ported to 11 it still doesn't work. But it is progress and thanks for your reply!